# Too many redirects when using CloudFront + Lambda + CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I've set up two distributions in Amazon CloudFront. Both origins point to the same bucket. The bucket has a redirect to an API Gateway if the requested resource is not found. The API Gateway executes a Lambda function that generates the resource, here resizes it. Once finished, it redirects to a definable URL (later called Lambda redirect URL). In the problematic case this redirect URL is a cdn URL which is mapped to one of the distributions as the Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs).

The following diagram shows the flow:

[image]

Now, for simplicity I invoke this flow by accessing a not yet existing resource via the CloufFront distribution URL. Via two different distributions: **I** a distribution with a Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) set to the cdn.example.de and **II** a distribution without. Otherwise the distributions are identical, e.g. have the same bucket as their origin.

In case of accessing direction **I** I get `too many redirects` in the browser. In case of accessing **II** everything works fine, meaning, I end up with the resized image and having the CDN URL in the address.

[image]

What works: the request to **I** also **creates the resource**. Thus, the Lambda function is invoked successfully. Also, if I request a resource via *I* that was built by *II* everything works fine. Thus, the problem is, that the redirect of the CloudFront distribution is somehow cached. But this is the part I don't get: The Lambda function redirects to the CDN only once the resource has been successfully created and put back to the S3 bucket. Thus, the redirect should not be endles. It should be CloudFront -> Buckets website -> API Gateway -> CDN (for the first time) -> CloudFront -> Bucket -> delivered!

Interestingly, if I set the Lambda redirect URL to the bucket endpoint, it works like a charm.

**Question**: How can I solve the `too many redirects` problem if I set up CNAME with a CloudFront distribution in combination with a Lambda function. This should be standard

Comment: If would be helpful if you could provide real URLs for an example... but if the first CDN caches the redirect, that would explain the loop.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I thinkg the first CDN is not part of the issue. I guess simply the CloudFront distribution caches the redirect. TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is a bit misleading as there is only one loop. After the second redirect the resource should be available. I think I just have to redirect to another CDN in the end, e.g. cdn2.example that points to another CloudFront distribution with the same bucket.

Comment: Setting TTL's in CloudFront distribution to 0 fixed issue for me in very similar case

Comment: After setting TTL to 0, I still see TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error few seconds, and then redirects to an image.